# async wcf service - need to call open() explicitly?

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous

Lame question but when you call a wcf service asynchronously, do you need to issue a

`client.Open()` explicitly first or does the async call handle all of that for you?

I am not using a channel factory.

Comment: If you´re not using a channel factory, does that mean that you are using the proxy generated by SvcUtil?

Comment: yes, I'm using a service reference in visual studio with "generate async methods" checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you dont have to call open, get yourself the client and call the async method, the framework will handle the rest.